# Merge attributes using spatial join where Target and Join feature is the same

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, spatial-join

I have a single polyline feature class and i need to merge one of the attributes together based on a common identifier using a delimiter (i.e. |).

I was certain Spatial Join using the one feature class as both the Target and Join features would be the answer (I have tried various settings tried using ONE TO MANY, 'Identical To', join with pipe delimiter on 'RUFI_wlen').

But it doesn't produce the results. There are multiple rows per UFI in the results.

Using ESRI ArcMap 10.5.

This image is the input attribute table:

[image: attribute table]

The desired result would be:

```
ROW 1: 
1152, 03329_R M WILLIAMS WAY_RC__10|03492_AYR ST_RC__18|03580_AYR ST_RC__61
ROW 2: 
1153, 03329_R M WILLIAMS WAY_RC__10| 03492_AYR ST_RC__18 |03580_AYR ST_RC__61
etc.
```

Comment: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/dissolve.htm perhaps? You might need to create a new field that separates your RFU_wlen into the strings you want to merge on, though.